# Composition and Limits

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Suppose that $f$ is a continuously differentiable function with $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)=k$ and $g$ is a Lipschitz continuous function. Prove that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} g(x,f(x))-g(x,k)=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $C$ be a Lipschitz constant for $g$ and let $\epsilon > 0$. Then, since $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=k$, there is some $M>0$ such that $$x > M \quad \implies\quad  |f(x)-k|<\frac{\epsilon}{C}.$$ It follows that
$$x > M \quad \implies\quad |g(x,f(x))-g(x,k)| \leq C|f(x)-k| < C\frac{\epsilon}{C}= \epsilon,$$
i.e. $\lim_{x \to \infty}g(x,f(x))-g(x,k)=0$.